# Database Synchronization Failed in Ektron V8.6.1 during initial sync

Tags: .net, content-management-system, synchronization, ektron

I had created a synchronization server relationship and try to do initial sync.
But the Database Synchronization Failed.

please find the log below that i got during initial sync.

```
Synchronization Status [ProfileId: 4294967295]
Synchronization Failed
9/2/2013 5:55:02 AMRunning Pre-Initialization Tasks
9/2/2013 5:55:03 AMSynchronization is Initializing
9/2/2013 5:55:03 AMValidating Synchronization Details
9/2/2013 5:55:03 AMSynchronization is Initialized
9/2/2013 5:55:03 AMServer Index Update Started
9/2/2013 5:55:03 AMServer Index Update Completed
9/2/2013 5:55:03 AMDatabase Synchronization Started
9/2/2013 5:55:04 AMDatabase Synchronization Failed
Invalid scopeId 033275af-99c5-4c10-b22d-54be7208e12a Invalid server index. 
Local server index:3, Remote server index:3 Local Exception:\nRemote Exception
9/2/2013 5:55:04 AMSynchronization Has Failed
Invalid scopeId 033275af-99c5-4c10-b22d-54be7208e12a Invalid server index. 
Local server index:3, Remote server index:3 Local Exception:\nRemote Exception
Synchronization Was Canceled.
```

What I had done:

- Back up the MINCMS861 from B and restored in A  as MINCMS861Test
- Create New Sync Server relationship in A with Synchronization
  Direction from B (MINCMS861) to A (MINCMS861Test).
- Do the Initial    Sync

Can you please let me know if I’m on the right track?

I got this as [solution](http://dev.ektron.com/WorkArea/threadeddisc/print_thread.aspx?id=74&g=posts&t=40053) but i don't know where to update the  server index values.

Comment: dbo.sync_settings is the only lead I saw of a cursory search of database tables, and that feels like a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

There's a different process if you're wanting to establish a sync relationship in which you also back up and restore the database between two systems - it's more complicated that way. The most common, and most successful approach is to have your Source server (B in  your description above) sync to a min site and min database on the Destination (A in your description).

So the process would be:

1. Assuming your database and site on B are complete, leave them as-is.
2. Install Ektron and set up a CMS400min site, with database on server A. (Do not copy the DB or site files from B to A.)
3. Run the Security Configuration utility on both systems to generate server certificates.
4. Exchange certificates between the servers and run the Security Configuration utility on each system to import each other's certificates.
5. Log in to Ektron on server B.
6. Create your eSync profile, pushing data from B to A.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

1. Backup and restore the CMS database to target server.
2. Run security configuration utility on both the servers.
3. Apply the remote server certificate on each server.
4. correct the Assetsmanagement config file, give correct values for the keys "UserDomain","Domain Name","Storage Location".
5. Recycle the app pool on each servers.
6. Restart the ektron windows service.
7. create the esync profile
8. run esync.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution on the Ektron Customer Portal for this issue
https://portal.ektron.com/KB/10329/

....

In sum, for a given relationship or 'forest' of relationships, the 'share_index' values must match, while the 'server_index' values must be unique.

For example, the error "Max index do not match. Local index:12, Remote index:11" would indicate that the 'share_index' values do not match.  Use the following SQL query to retrieve the values from a given database, and compare the returned values among the other databases in the relationship:

select server_index, share_index from settings

If you so choose, you can then correct the issue with the following queries:

** Note ** Back-up -every- database in the relationship prior to any direct-editing **

To update 'server_index':

update settings set server_index = xxx

To update 'share_index':

update settings set share_index = xxx

In either case, replace 'xxx' with the value you wish to set.  Also, note that the 'share_index' value increments each time a new server is added to the 'forest', it must thus be larger than the largest of the 'server_index' values.

Comment: Please include the main element of the answer directly in your answer, link tend to become invalid